# use of sed and perl to do the word processing, copying lines from one file to another

Tags: linux, lines, copying

I am new to Linux and have a challenging task.

I have 3 data files, and need to do the following:

1. Go to line 31 of file 1, delete it
2. Read 1 line from file 2 and add in place of deleted line
3. Go to line 97 of file 1 delete it and then read the line 1 from file 2 and add in place of that deleted line in file 1.

The thing is also important to keep the same file i.e file , it is not to be changed.

I tried different versions of `sed` and `perl`, with buffer copying tricks but was not successful.

I am open for all suggestions and request the experts to give me suggestions.

Comment: How can you delete & replace lines in files but not change the files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter I mean to say that the file is offcourse changed but I dont want to get a new file .. like   using -i option with sed

Comment: I thank you for reply to my post.. As I expect some suggestions from experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find a reference to the 3rd file in your question, but if you mean replace line number 31 of file 1 with the 1st line of file 2, and replace line number 97 of file 1 with the 2nd line of file 2:

```
sed -i -e '30R f2
31d;96R f2
97d' f1
```

The new lines are important after f2 so sed knows that it is the end of the file name.

Note that the `R` command is a GNU extension, it is not standard.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Merci . http://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagnegne.   It is working perfect for me now. I will use it with loops and to change continuously to keep updating the file during my simulation. This was perfect. I cant vote up, but I want to  :)

Comment: I have another question that will help me in the completion of code.. what if I have to copy line 15 of file 2 and copy in place of line 20 of file 1.  I will be waiting for the completion, best regards.

Comment: If you have to copy line 15 of file2 at line of 20 of file1, and still have to copy line line 1 of file2 at line 31 of file1, I would suggest generating a new file2 (let call it nfile2) with its 1st line being line 15 of file2 and its second line being line 1 of file2, and using the above script with nfile2.  It is not that hard to generate nfile2 using `sed -n -e '1x;15{G;p}' file2 > nfile2'.  If you also need line 2 of file2 at line 97 of file1, generate nfile2 with `sed -n -e '1x;2H;15{G;p}' file2 > nfile2'.

Comment: However, if you need out of order line replacement, awk might be a better tool.  You could read file2 in the BEGIN part of the awk script, and then print back file1 as it is read doing special treatment with the line you want to replace.  However, awk does not have a `-i` option as sed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/851677/jfgagne        thank you for your such a nice explanation.  it worked for me.  best regards